# setInterval won't restart when cleared with clearInterval and reset with setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a countdown which uses setInterval to countdown from one minute in one second intervals. 
When a "start" button is clicked, it starts the countdown using setInterval(countdown, 1000). When I click another button, it clears the countdown. If I press the "start" button again, the interval does not countdown again using setInterval(countdown, 1000) - it is stuck at one minute.

Am I using setInterval right? I expect setInterval to begin counting down in 1s intervals once the start button is clicked again.

Please find relevant code below, and thanks for your time.

```
//Start button
$("#startQuiz").click(function () {
            $(".questionStart").css("display", "none").removeClass("questionActive");
            $(".questionStart").next().addClass("questionActive");

            startTimer = true;
            setInterval(countdown, 1000);

        });

//countdown code (at a global scope)
var countdown = setInterval(function () {

    if (startTimer === true) {    
            //timer code here
        }
    }

}, 1000);

//reset countdown code called on separate button click
function levelCloseReset() {
    startTimer = false;
    clearInterval(countdown);
}
```

Comment: The first argument to `setInterval()` should be a function. The `setInterval` function itself returns a *number*, a key that's used later to clear the timer.

Comment: @Pointy thanks for your guidance. It seems my understanding of setInterval is wrong. You've mentioned it returns a number - what is the nature of this number and can it be used to reset the timer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```js
  (function() {
    let counter = null;
    let timer = 60;
    $("#startQuiz").click(function () {
        resetQuiz(); // reset the quiz;
        $(".questionStart").css("display", "none").removeClass("questionActive");
        $(".questionStart").next().addClass("questionActive");
        $("#startQuiz").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#stopQuiz").attr("disabled", false);
        $("#count-down").text("Time Remaining: " + timer);
        counter = setInterval(countDown, 1000);
    });

    $("#stopQuiz").click(function () {
        $(".questionStart").css("display", "none").removeClass("questionActive");
        $(".questionStart").next().addClass("questionActive");
        $("#startQuiz").attr("disabled", false);
        $("#stopQuiz").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#count-down").text("Stopped: ");
        resetQuiz();
    });

    function countDown() {
      if(timer === 0) {
        $("#count-down").text("Time Over: ");
        $("#startQuiz").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#stopQuiz").attr("disabled", true);
        resetQuiz();
      } else {
        $("#count-down").text("Time Remaining: " + --timer);
      }
      
    }
    
    function resetQuiz() {
      timer = 60;
      clearInterval(counter);
    }
  }
  )();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="count-down"></div>
    <button type="button" id="startQuiz">Start Quiz</button>
    <button type="button" id="stopQuiz" disabled>Stop Quiz</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This solution helped me figure out my problem. I will mark this as the answer.